# Oracle. Old Partitions having Stale Statistics

Tags: oracle, partitioning, performance-tuning

Our production database tables are range partitioned based on date.

Some of the tables and indexes have hundreds of partitions. And some of partitions which are old ( based upon partition key ) have stale statistics. Some of these partitions are most likely not being accessed by our queries.

Sometimes the server exhibits performance problems but we cannot be sure whether the problem is due to those old partitions or not.

Is it a good idea to PROACTIVELY update the statistics in those old partitions ?

Is there a possibility that the performance degrade if we simply update stats on all such partitions ?

Answer (score 2):

Normally it does not hurt to make sure that your statistics are up to date. Statistics are up to date if since the last gathering there have been no significant number of updates/deletes/inserts/truncates in the partition.

For large partitioned tables it would be good to use incremental statistics and have the granularity setup by partition. Doing so prevents full table gatherings, which is not very sensible to do if you can prevent this using the table statistics settings.

There is always a chance that your performance degrades if you updated the statistics. In that case it is quite easy to restore the previous version. If that is the case, there is something strange happening. If your table has a regular distribution of data and all rows have about the same length, there will not quickly be a problem.

If your performance degrades after updating the old partitions, it might be wise to restore the previous version and to lock the stats. This is a signal that new statistics are not welcome.

so normally it is ok.

Comment: Can you clarify *"have the granularity setup by partition"*? If you mean the granularity parameter for dbms_stats.gather_table_stats, my understanding is only `AUTO` maintains synopses and rolls partition stats up to the table level. However, this is risky because dbms_stats may decide it needs to rescan the entire table taking many hours, so instead you specify `PARTITION`, but I am not sure whether this maintains synopses.

Comment: The trick here is not to have stats on the global level and to always make sure you put statistics on newly created partitions. This makes that we see the values also on the global level.

Comment: Newly created partitions are empty so I don't see any value in gathering stats at that point. Also, global statistics are the whole point of incremental stats and are used for example when the query involves multiple partitions, so I'm not sure what you are suggesting by *"The trick here is not to have stats on the global level"*.

Comment: If you delete the global stats and gather stats on all partitions, you see the values appear at table level too. Oracle is a bit funny about partitions without statistics. It will manage the stats but not create them. It does not harm to tell the optimizer that a partition is empty. This works from v11 and up. (Did not check v19)

Comment: *It does not harm to tell the optimizer that a partition is empty.* It does if they are not empty, for example if you gathered stats "on newly created partitions" that were later populated by a batch load. Also, by "The trick here is not to have stats on the global level" it sounds like you're saying to let Oracle manage global stats using the incremental statistics feature by gathering stats using granularity `AUTO`.

Comment: I agree on that. Wrong info hurts. That is why I advice the developers involved in operations that cause significant changes, like big loads/deletes and sometimes updates(depending on what is done) to gather stats on the partitions they did hit.